# Chaos Monkey Spring Boot works in dev environment but doesn't work for functional test in test environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, cucumber-junit, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am trying to run `ChaosMonkey` for my resilience tests. I'm using `Spring Boot` and the `WebTestClient` Class to make api requests in cucumber functional resilience tests. The responses show that Chaos Monkey latency is configured correctly, but I don't see any latency. Does anyone know why it's not working for my tests?

My watcher configuration (request from within the test):

```
{
    "controller": false,
    "restController": false,
    "service": false,
    "repository": false,
    "component": false,
    "restTemplate": false,
    "webClient": false,
    "actuatorHealth": false,
    "beans": []
}
```

My assault configuration (request from within the test):

```
{
    "level":1,
    "latencyRangeStart":5000,
    "latencyRangeEnd":5000,
    "latencyActive":true,
    "watchedCustomServices":["com.my.correct.repository.ClassName"]
}
```

My `application-test.properties` file matches my `application-dev.properties` file, which DOES WORK.

```
spring.profiles.include=resilience4J-test,chaos-monkey
server.error.include-message=always

chaos.monkey.enabled=true

management.endpoint.chaosmonkey.enabled=true
management.endpoint.chaosmonkeyjmx.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,chaosmonkey
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
management.endpoint.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
```

I'm using `Chaos Monkey 2.5.4` and `Spring Boot 2.3.12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just figured out that you need to add @ComponentScan to the test app so that Chaos monkey can discover the components and annotations. It works fine for me now.